# How to delete everything in folder?

Tags: linux, unix

I've tried executing `sudo rm *` and it does not remove everything. (I probably have lots of objects in there which I don't need.)

I'm not asking whether it is OK to remove everything in `/tmp`, I'm asking how to do it. Is there a shell script that can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
rm -rf *
```

-r for recursive (also subdirectories) and -f for force (also write-protected files). But be careful in using this.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man rm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm):

> By default, `rm` does not remove directories. Use the **--recursive** (**-r** or **-R**) option to remove each listed directory, too, along with all of its contents.

So try this:

```
sudo rm -r *
```